# Matlab GUI Edit Box Enter Not Working

Tags: matlab

So basically I'm trying to give an option to plot data directly by pressing enter within an edit box in a GUI, instead of having to press the pushbutton associated with plotting the data. But I'm running into a problem that it doesn't update the edit box handle correctly before submitting to the pushbutton (e.g. I'll type in 23 and press enter, which should plot 23 periods of data but current registers as an empty string). But if I hit enter twice, then it does correctly execute the function. The code I've got for this is:

```
function edit1_KeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
currentKey = get(gcf,'CurrentKey');
if currentKey == 'return'
  pushbutton1_Callback(handles.pushbutton1, eventdata, handles)
  guidata(gcf,handles)
end
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I've encountered this problem once. I think that there was some kind of 3d party DLL that reads keystrokes. If I manage to recall it, I will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Which property on the edit box are you using to retrieve the entered data?

You should find that the 'string' property matches what the user has entered but the 'value' property contains the data in the edit box before the editing started.

One way of handling this is to call:

```
 set(handles.edit1,'value',str2double(get(handles.edit1,'string')))
```

before calling the button callback.